# Reactjs: How to get values from array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I am a beginner in rectjs. In my project, there is a list of objects stored in "groupedItems", and using sort() to order them and stored them into a variable "numAscending".

[image]

Now its structure is in the above picture. but I want to change them like in the below picture.

[image]

Here is the code which I tried.

```
 groupedItems.map((items)=>{
                numAscending = [...items].sort((a, b) => a.subsolution_name - b.subsolution_name);
                temp.push({numAscending})
            })
            console.log("temp", temp)


            // result = temp.map((option, key) => {
            //     console.log("eeeeeeee", option)
            //     option.map((item)=>{
            //         console.log("iteee", item)
            //     })
            // });

            // console.log('result', result);
```

I tried to fix it but failed (lines are started with //). Please give me a suggestion to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably could flatten the `groupedItems` array's element values, which appear to be arrays, and *then* sort the overall result array.

Example:

```
const result = groupedItems
  .flat(Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY)
  .sort((a, b) => a.subsolution_name - b.subsolution_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce it to get the array and then sort it

```
const reducedItems = groupedItems.reduce((prev,curr)=>{
    return [...prev,...curr.numAscending]
},[]);
const sortedItems = reducedItems.sort((a, b) => a.subsolution_name - b.subsolution_name);
```